# Is it possible to develop a custom graph method for shortest route calculation on GIS-maps?

Tags: graph, gis

I'm doing the project for my diploma, and there's a serious problem. I need to find the shortest route from A to B on the GIS-map using graphs. I found some methods in the program, such as Dijkstra and A*, but I need to use another one, that I want to make up by myself. Is it possible? I haven't found any information about it in the whole internet :(

I tried a lot of methods, but it didn't help. I need a graph method exactly on GIS-maps.

Comment: Dijkstra is the algorithm for finding shortest route in a graph.  If you insist in "making up" your own, why are you asking for someone else to "make up" one for you?

Comment: My best guess is that you do not really want to make up your own algorithm.  You really want some help with implementing Dijkstra on a particular platform ( GIS-maps ).  If this is so, edit your question so it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If your "GIS-map" is **vector**, you can use the [boost::graph](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) lib to find the shortest paths. But first, you should convert your vector to the "graph". You can set your **junction** to the **vertex**, and the **road** to the **edge**.
If your "GIS-map" is **raster**, you can also use the boos::graph lib, first you should convert the raster to the "graph", you can refer to this [article](http://www.maxgcoding.com/AStar/). Or you can use the [path_planning](https://github.com/vss2sn/path_planning#algorithms) lib for a grid based shortest path search.